# Fade in and out (flashing) text using JavaScript in C# ASP.Net application

Tags: javascript, c#, css, asp.net, webforms

In part of my application (WebForm ASP.Net) I change a text on the web page. To take user attention to the change, I want to fade-out the text until completely make it disappear, then change the text and then fade-in to show the new text.

I have partially implemented this in JavaScript. I can fade-out and fade-in a text using below codes:

**JavaScript**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function toHex(d) {
        return ("0" + (Number(d).toString(16))).slice(-2).toUpperCase()
    }

    var direction = 1;
    var timer_is_on = 0;
    var rgb = 0;

    function timedCount() {
        var lab = document.getElementById('lblMessage');
        if (direction == 1) {
            rgb = rgb + 15;
        }
        if (direction == -1) {
            rgb = rgb - 15;
        }
        lab.style.color = "#" + toHex(rgb) + toHex(rgb) + toHex(rgb);;
        if (rgb >= 255 || rgb <= 0) {
            if (direction == 1) {
                direction = -1;
            }
            else {
                timer_is_on = 0;
                return;
            }
        }
        setTimeout(timedCount, 50);
    }

    function startEffect() {
        if (!timer_is_on) {
            timer_is_on = 1;
            direction = 1;
            rgb = 0;
            timedCount();
        }
    }
</script>
```

**ASPX**

```
<form id="frm" runat="server">
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="pnlMain" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <div style="width: 400px; margin: 0 auto; text-align: center; font-size: x-large">
                <span id="lblMessage">No Record is Selected</span>
            </div>
            <button onclick="startEffect()">Start!</button>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
</form>
```

**The Problem**

I don't know 2 things:

1. How I change the text after fade-out completes
2. How to do all these from code-behind in C#.

Note: I want to do that without jQuery or any other JavaScript library.

Comment: Just a suggestion, it would be better if you made the fade in and fade out with css animations instead. As for your questions, it isn't clear based on what you want to change the text. And for your second question, you can't really put js/css code in c# as each serves different purpose. It's a bit problematic to make what you, because you are using webforms and they work based on postbacks which will reload your page with new data, which defeats the point of user "interaction" with the page with js/css animations.

Comment: You are right. I have tried many things and could not make it work because all asp.net postback and updatepanel tricks. I think my biggest problem is mixing the JavaScript with Code-Behind. if it was all JS, it would be much easier but I have server-side code involved.

Comment: If you can you should try MVC instead of webforms, if you need to stay with webforms, then depending on the amount of data, you can either get them with ajax call and serve them through own handler and apply js/css appropriately, or you can create the page with the data already and just change visibility, or change the data on postback and just do fade in animation, dumping the fade out so you don't delay your users from getting the page with new data.Regardless it will be better to use css animations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there might be some CSS techniques to do this code simpler and shorter but to make your code compatible with all browsers I follow the way you are doing it.

You need to pass the new message to your JS function. I also changed the JS to pass the Id of the control so you can use the code for multiple elements in your page.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function toHex(d) {
        return ("0" + (Number(d).toString(16))).slice(-2).toUpperCase()
    }

    var direction = 1;
    var timer_is_on = 0;
    var rgb = 0;

    function timedCount(controlId, newMsg) {
        var lab = document.getElementById(controlId);
        if (direction == 1) {
            rgb = rgb + 15;
        }
        if (direction == -1) {
            rgb = rgb - 15;
        }
        lab.style.color = "#" + toHex(rgb) + toHex(rgb) + toHex(rgb);
        if (rgb >= 255 || rgb <= 0) {
            if (direction == 1) {
                direction = -1;
                lab.innerText = newMsg;
            }
            else {
                timer_is_on = 0;
                return;
            }
        }
        setTimeout(timedCount.bind(null, controlId, newMsg), 50);
    }

    function startEffect(controlId, newMsg) {
        if (!timer_is_on) {
            timer_is_on = 1;
            direction = 1;
            rgb = 0;
            timedCount(controlId, newMsg);
        }
    }
</script>
```

Also to solve post-back issue, you need to use hidden field to do the trick. This is important otherwise, your text will be restored on post-back.

```
<form id="frm" runat="server">
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="pnlMain" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:HiddenField ID="hfMessage" runat="server" />
            <div style="width: 400px; margin: 0 auto; text-align: center; font-size: x-large">
                <asp:Label ID="lblMessage" runat="server" Text="No Record is Selected"></asp:Label>
            </div>
            <asp:Button ID="btnFlash" runat="server" Text="Change Text" OnClick="btnFlash_Click" />
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
</form>
```

And this is the code-behind

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // on first load, store the text message in hidden field
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        hfMessage.Value = lblMessage.Text;
    }

    if (Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        // on postback, set the text message from hidden field which is populated in button click
        lblMessage.Text = hfMessage.Value;
    }
}

protected void btnFlash_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // This would be your message, I just used a date-time to create dynamic message.
    string newMessage = DateTime.Now.Second.ToString() + " Records Selected";

    // store the new message in hidden field to change the text on post-back, otherwise your message will be restored on post-back
    hfMessage.Value = newMessage;

    // call JS from code-behind, pass the control ID and the new message
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "flash", "startEffect('lblMessage', '" + newMessage + "');", true);
}
```

This was a challenging question :)